Solving the system $\dot{x} = -y-t, \dot{y} = x+t, x(0) = 1, y(0) = 0$
I have to solve the following system of ODEs
$$\dot{x} = -y-t, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \dot{y} = x + t \ \ \ \ \ x(0) = 1, y(0) = 0$$
My approach was as follows:
$F\Biggl(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\Biggr) = \Biggl(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\Biggr)\Biggl(\begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\Biggr) + \Biggl(\begin{matrix} - t \\ t \end{matrix}\Biggr)$
So, we have a linear and non-homogeneous system of differential equations. In order to solve this system, I wanted to use $\textbf{Duhamel's formula}$:
$x(t) = e^{tA}x_0 + \int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}g(s)ds$
Firstly, I computed the Matrix exponential. For that, I had to find the eigenvalues of $A = \Biggl(\begin{matrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\Biggr)$. I got two different eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$
$$\lambda_1 = i \ \ \ \ \ \ \lambda_2 = -i$$
which gave me the following general solution
$$x(t) = C_1e^{it} + C_2e^{-it}$$
Using $x(0) = 1$ and $y(0) = \dot{x}(0) = 0$, I got $C_1 = \frac{1}{2} = C_2$. So, the solution for the homogeneous system is given by
$$x_h(t) = e^{tA}x_0 = \frac{1}{2}\Bigl(e^{it} + e^{-it}\Bigr) = cos(t)$$
Now I wanted to compute the partial solution for:
$$e^{(t-s)A} = \Biggl(\begin{matrix}e^{-i(t-s)} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i(t-s)}\end{matrix}\Biggr) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ g(s) = \Biggl(\begin{matrix}-s \\ s \end{matrix}\Biggr)$$
I got the following Integral expression
$$x_p(t) = \int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}g(s)ds = \int_{0}^{t}\Biggl(\begin{matrix}e^{-i(t-s)} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i(t-s)}\end{matrix}\Biggr)\Biggl(\begin{matrix}-s \\ s \end{matrix}\Biggr)ds = \int_{0}^{t}\Biggl(\begin{matrix} -se^{-i(t-s)}\\ se^{i(t-s)} \end{matrix}\Biggr)ds$$
And now, I am a little bit stuck here, since I can't really compute the expression $\int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}g(s)ds$.
Could somebody help me to get to the full final solution of this problem? And maybe give some feedback about my general approach to this problem? I tried to apply the theory which we studied during the course.
Edit: After some advices, I realised that I computed just one part of the general solution to the homogeneous system $\dot{x} = -y, \dot{y} = x$.
So, since we have $x_h(t) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{it} + e^{-it})$, we can compute the general solution of the y-component by using
$$y(t) = -\dot{x} = -\Bigl(\frac{1}{2}(ie^{it} - ie^{-it})\Bigr) = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i} = \text{sin}(t)$$
Our two-dimensional general solution is then given by
$$x_h(t) = \Biggl(\begin{matrix}\text{cos}(t) \\ \text{sin}(t) \end{matrix}\Biggr)$$
As a result, our final solution takes the following form
$$x(t) = \Biggl(\begin{matrix} cos(t) - \int_{0}^{t}se^{-i(t-s)}ds \\ sin(t) + \int_{0}^{t}se^{i(t-s)}ds\end{matrix}\Biggr)$$
Using Integration by parts for every component, we get
$$x(t) = \Biggl(\begin{matrix} cos(t) + it - 1 + e^{-it} \\ sin(t) + it + 1 - e^{it}\end{matrix}\Biggr)$$

Hint: Integration by parts.

@Balajisb Yes, I know that. However, I just really wanted to see how to use Duhamel's formula in this two-dimensional context since I have never done that before. And now I don't understand how to get to the final solution. So far, I got
$x(t) = cos(t) + \int_{0}^{t}\Biggl(\begin{matrix}-se^{-it} \ se^{it} \end{matrix}\Biggr)ds$
and I am a little bit confused right now, since I get on the one hand a $cos(t)$ term and on the other hand this two-dimensional integral expression. So, I am a little bit stuck on that particular aspect.

$x(t) = \cos t + \int -se^{-it}\ ds,  y(t) = \sin t + \int se^{it}\ ds.$  And you can resolve each of them using integration by parts.

Yes, thank you! I edited my post. Could anybody have a look on my final solution?

Note that your final solution includes imaginary numbers while your initial differential equation had no source of these. This should be a clear check that your proposed answer is incorrect.

We have the system
$$x' = Ax + g(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}x + \begin{pmatrix} -t \\ t\end{pmatrix}$$
The eigenvalues / eigenvectors are
$$\lambda_{1,2} = \pm i, v_{1,2} = \begin{pmatrix} \pm i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
The leads to the matrix exponential
$$e^{tA} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos (t) & -\sin (t) \\ \sin (t) & \cos (t) 
\end{pmatrix}$$
Next, we form
$$e^{(t-s)A}.g(s) = \begin{pmatrix} s \sin (s-t)-s \cos (s-t) \\ s \sin (s-t)+s \cos (s-t)  \end{pmatrix}$$
Now we integrate
$$\int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}g(s)ds = \begin{pmatrix} -1 -t+\cos(t) + \sin (t) \\ 1 -t -\cos(t) +\sin (t) \end{pmatrix}$$
Now we can write
$\begin{align} x(t) &= e^{tA}x_0 + \int_{0}^{t}e^{(t-s)A}g(s)ds \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} \cos (t) & -\sin (t) \\ \sin (t) & \cos (t) \\
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\  0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} -1 -t+\cos(t) + \sin (t) \\ 1 -t -\cos(t) +\sin (t) \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} -1-t+\sin (t)+2 \cos (t) \\1 -t -\cos(t) +2 \sin (t) \end{pmatrix} \end{align}$
Update: We will find the matrix exponential using these notes. For the eigenvalue (we only need to use either of the eigenvalues from the notes)
$$\lambda_1 = i, v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
We write
$$x_h(t) = e^{it} \begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = (\cos(t) + i \sin(t))\begin{pmatrix} i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} i \ \cos(t) - \sin(t) \\ i \sin(t) + \cos(t)\end{pmatrix} $$
From that, we treat $i$ as just a constant and can write
$$x_h(t) = c_1 \begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) \\ \sin(t) \end{pmatrix}  + c_2 \begin{pmatrix} -\sin(t) \\ \cos(t)\end{pmatrix}$$
The Fundamental Matrix is given by
$$\phi(t) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos (t) & -\sin (t) \\ \sin (t) & \cos (t) \end{pmatrix}$$
The inverse evaluated at zero
$$\phi^{-1}(0) = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
From this, we write
$$e^{tA} = \phi(t).\phi^{-1}(0)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos (t) & -\sin (t) \\ \sin (t) & \cos (t) 
\end{pmatrix}$$
I should also mention that there are many ways to find the matrix exponential, so that should be reviewed. For example, these notes (look at item $(5))$.

Just one question: how did you get the matrix exponential $e^{tA}$?

I was a little sloppy in my writeup - but cleaned it up. I am not sure which method you are currently using for the matrix exponential, but you should practice those and make sure you follow.

For this particular equation you have a much easier procedure. Taking the derivative of the first equation, you get $\ddot x = -\dot y -1$, which means that $\ddot x + x +t +1 = 0$. The initial conditions are $x(0)=1$ and $x'(0)=0$.
This linear second order equation can be easily solved to get $x(t)=-t+\sin (t)+2 \cos (t)-1$.

Using $z=x+iy$ the equations combine to
$$
\dot z = iz+(-1+i)t.
$$
Now this has an easy integrating factor $e^{-it}$ to give
$$
z(t)=z(0)e^{it}+(-1+i)\int_0^tse^{i(t-s)}\,ds. 
$$
